# What is the correct way to start a Runnable infinitely at fixed rate?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I was practicing making metronome in Android Studio(Java). I came across many method to start a indefinite loop with a task at fixed rate but all failed to keep up the rhythm and causes delay between beat or sometime playing two quickly. I used nanosec method, Handler post delayed method, scheduler etc. What should be the correct way to do this without lag and I can be assured? By the way I am using SoundPool to play the beats.

Comment: How exact do you need to be?  Android is not a real time OS, if you expect millisecond timing you're just not going to get it.

Comment: Take any normal Metronome app on Google play. I just want consistency and I also don't have problem with very slight variance in delay.

Comment: I doubt any of them work by doing anything timing based if they need that level of accuracy.  On a Linux based OS (like Android) you have no control over how frequently you're scheduled and the exact timing of being scheduled.  To get that type of consistency you need a totally different type of operating system.As for Scheduler vs Handlervs other-  they all do the same things behind the scenes. So the question is how exact do you actually need to be, to figure out what horrible hacks you need to do.

Comment: Let me elaborate. There is my fav. app on Google Play Store named "Beatronome". If I play that metronome it has very consistent rhythm and no sudden delay or quick play of successive beat. So my question can be in a way that how can I implement the same in Java i.e. without any noticeable rhythm changes.

Comment: There will always be some delay, as the OS isn't made to do these things exactly.  The question is how much will you put up with vs other tradeoffs.  The easiest way is just to not do it at all.  Lets say you want 140 beats per minute.  Record an audio file with 140 beats per minute that's say a minute long.  Play that.  Then you'd only have a possible issue at the 1 minute mark.  That's the technique which would be absolutely smoothest.  The less you have to deal with timing, the fewer issues you'll have.  Also, if using SoundPool make sure you only load it once and reuse the loaded sound.

Comment: Also, I'd use the SoundPool setLoop function, rather than calling it for each individual time.  You can always stop it later if needed.

Comment: I am beginner. Can you please provide some reference or link how to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226707/discussion-between-user9339131-and-gabe-sechan).